# PHP script to use for HTTP post request

Tags: php, http-post

Hope someone could spare time to help a rookie.  I have to set up my server and then provide a supplier with the URL of the page which has to be able to receive a HTTP-Post request like the following - For each post received, your page will have to answer with a "+OK", in order to confirm the correct delivery of the notification.

```
    POST /yourpage.php HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.yoursite.com
    Content-Length: 215
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Accept-Language: it
    Cache-Control: no-cache

destination=%2B40757732753&text=sms+test+example&originator=%2B391234567890&date_time=20160606074445
```

What would be the best way to go about this instruction? I have some basic knowledge of PHP (still learning), so we can use PHP.
Thanks in advance
Marinda

Answer (score 0):

You need learn about global variables in PHP, php has **$_POST** able to get content sended on body of post and do something with it.

```
<?php
// this will create a variable with data of destination sent
$destination = $_POST['destination']

...
// just print +OK
echo "+OK"
```

But if you want send SMS to Mobile, you need use services to send for you, in general has a cost for this and able to send a limited number of SMSs depend your plan.

I hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

Check $_POST variable. It's a kind of special variable for this language. Then, you can:

```
<?php

    $isOK = true;

    // Check if POST parameter destination is set and it is not blank, you 
    // can repeat this validation with all your parameters, changing 
    // destination by its name.
    if (!isset($_POST['destination']) || trim($_POST['destination']) == '') {
        $isOK = false;
    }

    if ($isOK) {
        echo "+OK";
    }
```